# Is there a closed form solution for the Hellinger Distance between two Wishart distributions?

Tags: distributions, wishart-distribution, hellinger

Given two Wishart distributions $X_0 \sim W_{p_0}(V_0,n_0)$, $X_1 \sim W_{p_1}(V_1,n_1)$, what is the Hellinger Distance between them? Can it be obtained in closed form assuming $p_0 = p_1$?

---

For reference, the Wishart probability density function is ($x$ is a $p\times p$ PD matrix):

$$f_X(x)=\frac{|x|^{(n-p-1)/2}e^{-(1/2)\operatorname{tr}(V^{-1}x)}}{2^{np/2}|V|^{n/2}\Gamma_p(n/2)}$$

The Hellinger Distance is:

$$H^2(f,g)=1-\int\sqrt{f(x)g(x)}dx$$